# Как в woocommerce сделать отображение товаров не плиткой а списком по умолчанию?

Tags: wordpress

есть магазин, надо сделать чтоб по умолчанию отображались товарі не плиткой а именно списком

пробовал в теме искать (Porto), пробовал в настройках вукомерца(ничего не нашел), пробовал в разделе Внешний вид → настроить (тоже ничего нету)

Может какая функция или хук?